# Set folder permission by OU

Tags: active-directory, permissions, group-policy, directory

I'm attempting to setup folder permissions on my DC to a shared desktop. I have an OU containing the users I want to allow to view this folder, and a GPO which handles the permissions linked to the OU.

However, I can only find a way to allow access for specific users, and not for all the users within an OU.

I would rather not have to add all the users, and keep it updated rather than just putting the users in the correct OU initially and then needing to do nothing else.

Is this actually possible, because I can't seem to find any solid examples online.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An OU is not a security principal and cannot be used to grant access to resources, such as files and folders. You'll want to create a security group, add the users to this group, and grant access to the group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-principals